# Mongoose $inc updateMany cannot increment with non-numeric argument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Node API, where we have Mongo collection of profiles, and every profile have subscription_plan which represent rest of the days they have paid for using app.
Now, i works on part of the backend which should decrease subscription_plan of all profiles by 1. 
The problem is, subscription_plan is declared as String, so I can't just decrease it by 1
I tried with this after getting some tips here:

```
router.put('/reduceSubscription', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const updatedProfiles = await Profile.updateMany({ is_active: true }, [
            {
                $set: {
                    subscription_plan: {
                        $toString: {
                            $subtract: [{ $toInt: '$subscription_plan' }, 1]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]).exec();
        console.log(updatedProfiles);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message });
    }
});
```

After testing in postman, i got message:

```
"msg": "Failed to parse number 'NaN' in $convert with no onError value: Bad digit \"N\" while parsing NaN"
```

I would appreciate any help or code snippet that will help me solve this problem.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do (as the error states) is not possible with the current schema simply because your `Profile` model schema defines `subscription_plan` as a `String` and `$inc` only works on numeric fields.

Either change the schema type for that field or use the [aggregate pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-method-agg-pipeline) to update the value by creating a pipeline that has a set of aggregation pipeline operations i.e. 1) get the current value, 2) convert it to a numeric value using [`$toInt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/), 3) decrement the value with [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) and 4) set the new value back to string using [`$toString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/):

```
router.put('/reduceSubscription', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Profile.updateMany(
            { is_active: true },
            [
                { '$set': {
                    'subscription_plan': {
                        '$toString': {
                            '$subtract': [
                                { '$toInt': '$subscription_plan' },
                                1
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                } }
            ]
        ).exec();
        res.json('Profiles updated');
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message });
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your code snippet,  postman don't throw error, it sends Profiles updated json, but when i look at my frontend, value in database is still same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206523/discussion-between-chridam-and-seven).